# Postgres Syntax error while calling a built in function within a user defined function

Tags: postgresql

I have a jsonb array that looks like this

```
[{"name": "ARM", "object_key": "GOB-1211"}, {"name": "foo", "object_key": "GOB-1234"}]
```

I'm trying to write a postgresql function to get me
`{GOB-1211, GOB-1234}`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_object_keys(jsonb_array jsonb)
RETURNS text[] AS $$
DECLARE
  object_keys text[];
BEGIN
  FOR item IN jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array) LOOP
    object_keys := array_append(object_keys, item->>'object_key');
  END LOOP;
  RETURN object_keys;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But this throws an error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "jsonb_array_elements"
LINE 6:   FOR item IN jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array) LOOP
```

Could anyone point to me what I am doing wrong? Or maybe there is a better construct that I can use in a join or a where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the for loop expects you to declare the variable as you iterate over it - declare the `item` before using it.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_object_keys(jsonb_array jsonb)
RETURNS text[] AS $$
DECLARE
  object_keys text[] := '{}';
  item jsonb;  -- HERE
BEGIN
  FOR item IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array) LOOP
    object_keys := array_append(object_keys, item->>'object_key');
  END LOOP;
  RETURN object_keys;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```